# Is there a way to hide/remove specific woocommerce admin menus?

Tags: menu, woocommerce, hide

I am using woocommerce for wordpress, but a lot of the admin menus are not used and I would like to clean it up.

I managed to hide/remove some menu's from woocommerce, but was not able to hide these:

under the tab "woocommerce" in admin, I would like to remove the menu: 
*"orders"
"reports"
"add-ons"*

and in "woocommerce > settings" I would like to remove: 
*"General"
"Checkout"
"Accounts"
"Emails"*

My guess is this can be done in the function.php, but I can't figure it out. Your help would be much appreciated.

Is this possible?

Comment: No one who can help me maybe?

Answer (score 0):

We can use below hooks to remove desired menu from woocommerce admin.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_taxonomy_menu_pages', 999 );

function remove_taxonomy_menu_pages() {

    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', 'product_attributes' );

     remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_shipping_class&post_type=product');
}
```

Comment: Hi first of all I apologize for the late answer, did not get a heads up I guess I just saw your answer. Thank you for that. I inserted it, but nothing seems to happen.  Do I still have to add something? Or do I put all the code inside the function.php?